# Tableau spatial join lines to polygons

Tags: spatial-join, tableau

Tableau [claims](https://www.tableau.com/2021-3-features#item-83231) that version [2021.3](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_spatial_join.htm) onward can do so. But actual examples are thin--not finding anything useful via Google. Finding plenty of crap--Tableau's data model relies on all data being visualized being joined, but any two files can be hacked together using an Outer Join with arbitrary matching fields. Tableau's been able to do a points/polygons join for years. ([Not what I want](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_spatial_join.htm)). I could (theoretically) join points to polygons by busting the line into points, relating points to a common line ID, and then spatial joining points to polygons, but... if I can figure that out, seems like it's already been implemented, and it's just how Tableau does it I'm flailing at.

It's gotta be Tableau. I could do it in ArcGIS/ArcMap/R in about ten seconds.

Comment: Tableau talks of joining and unioning spatial data, but it's either a table-join using a common field, overlaying data (like layers in ArcGIS), or hacking layers together to permit multiple unrelated data layers by adding dummy fields with common values to both maps.

Comment: 'Buffer and count' possible, but no the 'spatial join and aggregate' I was hoping for: https://datavis.blog/2022/02/08/buffer-functions-and-spatial-joins/

Answer (score 0):

"Under Data Source, select a spatial field to join by. Note: Geometry is the default field name for spatial file sources except in SQL Server, where users create field names. Spatial fields have a globe icon  next to them. For the second data source, select another spatial field. Click the = sign and then select Intersects from the drop-down menu. You can only intersect two spatial fields." https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_spatial_join.htm